# Washing machine drain hose retaining clip installation

Tags: washer

I have a new GE stacked washer / dryer.  The drain hose has a star type retaining clip.  I have a laundry box install that includes the supplies and the drain pipe.  I can push a couple of the tabs of the star into the drain area of the laundry box but I am not sure how many should be pushed in.

I looked in the manual for the washer but it didn't describe the installation manner they were expecting.  Maybe this retaining clip was just meant to retain the drain hose while shipping the unit?  If I didn't have a laundry box then I don't see how this clip would even be useful for a standpipe.

Any tips?

[image: drain hose retaining clip]
[image: laundry box]